# How to get lldb to work on M1 Big Sur?

Tags: macos, xcode, development, apple-silicon

This is on an M1 mini, running 11.1 with an updated Xcode.  (All pending updates have been applied.)  SIP has not been disabled (if it can even be, on the M1).

We have a program we're using to test an `mmap()` failure in our application being ported.  We build the test program like this:

```
cc -v -arch arm64 -m64 -Wl,-no_adhoc_codesign -o mapfail mapfail.c
```

Then, we sign it.  It appears to be correctly signed:

```
@macarm[git:master]$ codesign -vvv mapfail
mapfail: valid on disk
mapfail: satisfies its Designated Requirement
@macarm[git:master]$
```

We have enabled developer mode on the system.  We also added my user to the `_developer` group.  My user is not an administrator, but I tried it as one and got the same thing.

When we run the program it gets a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV), so we want to debug it with `lldb`, but this happens:

```
@macarm[git:master]$ lldb mapfail
(lldb) target create "mapfail"
Current executable set to '/Users/layer/mapfail' (arm64).
(lldb) run
error: process exited with status -1 (attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument))
(lldb)
```

Searches for this have yielded no information, even on the Apple developer forums.

More info.  I tried an entitlement added at `codesign` time, but that did not work.  Here's the entitlement I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
         <key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key>
         <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Anyone see a problem with this XML?

Comment: If I can dig up more information how to set this entitlement, I will edit my answer. I wanted to at least get something up with the specific error message and an Apple solution for Xcode users on iOS / macOS

Comment: Depending on how deep down the “compilation tools” chain this goes, we might want to migrate it to stack overflow. We had overlap in scope, but this is morphing into a different question based on new developments.what steps did you take to “enable developer mode” I don’t do that on any Mac that runs brew to compile source code, so I think you may be doing a lot of things unrelated to the core entitlement of get_task

Comment: @bmike I did post it there, too.  Mainly because it had more of the tags I wanted to use, noticed after I posted here.  I could delete the one over there and this one could be migrated.  Let me know if you want me to do that.

Comment: Flag or say the word if you prefer migration and well handle it. You’ll have to delete flag the dupe there... you can keep both arms well edit this here as well to cover the parts on topic and let SO dig into the details

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant answer from Apple on the entitlements needed to attach the `llvm` debugger to a process:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132797

The entitlement needed on macOS is **com.apple.security.get-task-allow** and I know how to add that in Xcode, but not yet from the command line compiler. You can verify the same on your Mac using console app to show the logs and then reproduce the error. Then search for **debugserver** in console and you will see the debugger starting and then failing to attach.

Here's a different error if you try to start Calculator.app in the debugger - it's hardened and doesn't have the entitlement so that fails just like your app - it's not about notarization or code signing, but about the debugging entitlement on the binary.

```
default 19:30:23.088087-0600    debugserver debugserver will use os_log for internal logging.
default 19:30:23.088429-0600    debugserver debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1200.0.44
 for arm64.
default 19:30:23.088489-0600    debugserver Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
error   19:30:23.090348-0600    debugserver error: MachTask::TaskPortForProcessID task_for_pid failed: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 17889, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure)
default 19:30:23.090378-0600    debugserver 1 +0.000000 sec [45e2/0303]: error: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 17889, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure) err = ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 17889, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure) (0x00000005
default 19:30:23.090329-0600    kernel  macOSTaskPolicy: (com.apple.debugserver) may not get the taskport of (Calculator) (pid: 17889): (Calculator) is hardened, (Calculator) doesn't have get-task-allow, (com.apple.debugserver) is a declared debugger
```

Comment: Thanks.  We don't use Xcode for the builds, so I've been searching for the command-line way to do this.  I made a plist file with `<key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key><true/>` but that didn't work.  I added the usual fluff around that (`<plist>`, et al) and that didn't work either.

Comment: Do you believe disabling SIP would allow `lldb` to work?  It might be the easiest thing, at this point (even though the machine is in a colo).

Comment: I added the entitlement I used in the original question, at the end.

Comment: No. You can try to run any program that lacks that entitlement and it will fail @dkl SIP is not your roadblock IMO.